# Outlook rule or autoreply based on words NOT used in subject

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I would like to send out an auto reply to all incoming emails unless there is a specific word in the subject. I am having a hard time finding a solution, is there an easy way to do this? Using Outlook 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a auto-reply template first and then create following rule:

[image]

You can also find useful information in this TechNet thread: [How to setup Auto Reply in Outlook](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c15dbdb8-edc4-41fc-933c-3fce25d83a91/how-to-setup-auto-reply-in-outlook?forum=outlook)